# Iframe has src but doesn't load body

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe

I'm creating an `iframe` in order to print a PDF that comes from an Azure Blob storage. This PDF is loaded correctly, but for any reason, it has the `src` attribute but not the `body`:

```
<iframe class="pdf-viewer" ng-if="f.isIframeable"
        src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=httpsmypdfurl.pdf">
    #document
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</iframe>
```

Original code of the iframe:

```
<iframe class="pdf-viewer" ng-if="f.isIframeable" src="{{f.url | srcViewer}}">
</iframe>
```

Why is this happening even if my src is correct? How can I try to reload it or ensure it works?

Comment: It looks like AngularJs is blocking the domain with it being external from your page, what is your filter `srcViewer` doing? It should be returning the URL as a trusted resource like `$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);`

Comment: No content is permitted in an `<iframe>` element. See [MDN HTML Reference - iframe element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).